# i can not understand what wrong with my react native app ///

Tags: react-native

info Installing the app...

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
25 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 23 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.

> Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\ANTOR ROY\Desktop\royapp\android\app\build\intermediates\stripped_native_libs\debug\out\lib' after 10 attempts

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 39s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ANTOR ROY\Desktop\royapp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c react-native run-android

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ANTOR ROY\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-03-02T09_18_41_856Z-debug.log

Comment: As the error states, are you sure to have your android development environment set up? You can find a complete guide here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

Comment: yes but still is not working

Comment: Try this `cd android && ./gradlew clean` then `npm react-native run-android`